# Reshape and concatenate within a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wanted to know if it exists an easy way to transform such a matrix :

`[[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]]`

into

```
[[1 ,2 ,5 ,6 ],
 [3 ,4 ,7 ,8 ],
 [9 ,10,13,14],
 [11,12,15,16]]
```

Which is equivalent to reshape each initial list into 2x2 matrices, and then concatenate them;
for instance 
`np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape((2,2))` gives  [[1,2],[3,4]]

`np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]).reshape((2,2))` gives   [[5,6],[7,8]]

so

```
np.concatenate((np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape((2,2)), np.array([5, 6, 7, 8]).reshape((2,2))), axis=1)
```

will give

```
array([[1 ,2 ,5 ,6 ],
       [3 ,4 ,7 ,8 ]])
```

etc...

It is indeed a dummy example since I need to deal with more (and bigger) matrices, I have to find a more straightforward method.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to "drop" the second dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with [`swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) and a [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) along the first axis:

```
np.concatenate(a.reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1], 2, -1)
                 .swapaxes(1,2)
                 .reshape(a.shape))

array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

Comment: Wow! That's impressive! Thank you so much! Now I just have to learn and understand this swapaxes method I didn't know :)

Comment: Finaly I couldn't apply it to my problem... I had Q.shape = (10,10,784), and I wanted, in the same way as in my example to find a (280,280) shaped matrix ; I ended up to use ```data = np.array([]) 
for l in Q: 
    ligne = np.array([])
    for s in l:
        if ligne.shape == (0,) :
            ligne = s.reshape((28,28))
        else:
            ligne = np.concatenate((ligne, s.reshape((28,28))), axis=1)
    if data.shape == (0,) :
        data = ligne
    else:
        data = np.concatenate((data, ligne), axis=0)
```

Comment: What are, in this case, a,b,c,d,e   for `np.concatenate(Q.reshape(a, b, c, -1).swapaxes(d,e).reshape(Q.shape))` ?

Comment: My bad I hardcoded the two first axes, try now @Netchaiev

Comment: Still not working (I obtain at the end a 100x784 matrix...), since in my matrix of interest Q, Q.shape[0] and Q.shape[1] will be 10 and, at some point I guess one must to turn the 784 long lists into 28x28 matrices...

Comment: Do you need the concatenate?